# 365 Custom Masterpages

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-masterpage, branding, composed-looks

What is the recommendation for going OnPrem to 365 when you currently have custom masterpages? Is the recommended pattern to move standard collaboration sites to composed looks and retain custom masterpages for highly branded sites/pages even though those won't get MS feature updates?

Answer (score 1):

Modifying or adding a custom Master Page is [not recommended](http://www.microsofttrends.com/2014/11/26/custom-master-pages-custom-site-templates-and-sandboxed-solutions-are-not-recommended-for-office-365-sites/), but I also read a [good post by Chris O'Brien](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2015/01/custom-master-pages-and-web-templates-in-office-365--thoughts.html) about the matter where he discuss when to use a custom master page. However since you are not in control of Microsoft updates to Office 365 it is still a risky path for production environments.

Best is if you can have all branding and customization via the "alternate css" (under change MasterPage ../_layouts/15/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx) and [javascript injection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn913116.aspx) - Let the javascript do the DOM modifications.